# The name "xxxx" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, xna

So I'm creating a Mario remake using *XNA* (following a tutorial as I go because my understanding is still very limited), and I came across an error for "text"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;


namespace PersonalProject.Managers
{
    class TileManager
    {

        ArrayList mTiles;

        public TileManager()
        {
            mTiles = new ArrayList();
        }

        public void AddTile(Texture2D tile, Vector2 pos)
        {
            mTiles.Add(new Tile(text, pos));
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            foreach (Tile tile in mTiles)
            {

            }
        }
    }
    class Tile
    {
        public Texture2D texture;
        public Vector2 position;

        public Tile(Texture2D text, Vector2 pos)
        {
            texture = text;
            position = pos;
        }
    }
}
```

Under

```
mTiles.Add(new Tile(text, pos));
```

I'm getting "The name 'text' does not exist in the current context" even though I have it in

```
public Tile(Texture2D text, Vector2 pos)
        {
            texture = text;
            position = pos;
        }
```

"pos" isn't outputting me any errors though, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *context* here is the following method:

```
public void AddTile(Texture2D tile, Vector2 pos)
{
    mTiles.Add(new Tile(text, pos));
}
```

The `text` variable is not in scope there.

I guess what you meant is:

```
public void AddTile(Texture2D tile, Vector2 pos)
{
    mTiles.Add(new Tile(tile, pos));
}
```

or

```
public void AddTile(Texture2D text, Vector2 pos)
{
    mTiles.Add(new Tile(text, pos));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't catch onto that.

Comment: Is my brain broken or all three of your code samples exactly identical?

Comment: @KirkWoll `Texture2D tile` vs `Texture2D text`

Comment: @Kirk that's what bite the asker in the first place ;) look at `tile` vs `text`

Comment: @Lucas, thanks. :)  (the evidence points to the broken brain)

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
public void AddTile(Texture2D tile, Vector2 pos)
    {
        mTiles.Add(new Tile(text, pos));
    }
```

With:

```
public void AddTile(Texture2D tile, Vector2 pos)
    {
        mTiles.Add(new Tile(tile, pos));
    }
```